# Is there a way to easily return the selected radio button from a group in kivy?

Tags: python, kivy, radio-button, kivy-language, radio-group

I have a radio button system set up to select a home team in a sports game analysis situation. The code is as follows below:

note the `Button`s have been abstracted to focus on the question instead of the code

```
<NamingScreen>:
    GridLayout:
        cols: 3
        rows: 4

        Button:
            
        Button:
  
        Button:

        Label:
            text: 'HomeTeam?'

        CheckBox:
            id: team1_radio
            active: True
            group: "home deciders"
            allow_no_selection: False
            on_active:
                root.manager.get_screen('name_screen').ids.team1_selected.text = 'Selected as\n Home'
                root.manager.get_screen('name_screen').ids.team2_selected.text = ''

        Label:
            id: team1_selected
            text: 'Selected as\n Home'

    ######## team 2 buttons from here

        Button:
           
        Button:

        Button:

        Label:
            text: 'Home Team?'

        CheckBox:
            id: team2_radio
            group: "home deciders"
            allow_no_selection: False
            on_active:
                root.manager.get_screen('name_screen').ids.team2_selected.text = 'Selected as\n Home'
                root.manager.get_screen('name_screen').ids.team1_selected.text = ''

        Label:
            id: team2_selected
            text: ''
```

I now need to know which checkbox was selected.
Is there a method that does something similar to the following

where `group("home_deciders").selected` returns `team1_radio` for example?

I know that it's possible to do it using functions in the python file to compare both `active` values in each checkbox, but I am looking for a more elegant solution

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

here is one way.  With this solution,the Python method will be called one time and will be sent an argument that indicates which button is active.

One can save some of the business of the kivy file by defining a new class at the top of you Kivy file.  It just avoids some of the repetitive lines.

```
<HomeDeciderCheckBox@CheckBox>
    group: "home deciders"
    allow_no_selection: False
    # on_active: root.select_screen(self._num) if self.active else None
    # OR
    on_active: app.select_screen(self._num) if self.active else None
```

In your Kivy layout assign each check box with a unique number, _num and choose just one to be Active at initialization.

```
HomeDeciderCheckBox:
    active: True
    id: team1_radio
    _num: 1
HomeDeciderCheckBox:
    id: team2_radio
    _num: 2
HomeDeciderCheckBox:
    id: another_unique_id
    _num: 3
```

In Python you can do the remaining logic.  I think this is good design because you have separation of concerns in which your Python code has the logic and your kivy code (the gui) just shows how to lay out the graphics.

Python:

```
def select_screen(self, selection):
    # and whatever other logic you need
    print(f"{selection}")
```